# How do I stop Windows 7 from changing the path of a shortcut to a mapped drive if the drive shows as disconnected?

Tags: windows-7, windows, networking, network-drive

How do I stop Windows 7 from changing the path of a shortcut to a mapped drive if the drive shows as disconnected? I have cases where I need to map a drive to a folder on the same machine. For some reason when I reboot or start that machine, the mapped drive doesn't reconnect until I double click on it in explorer or "my computer". If the user tries to open that program from a shortcut on the desktop, Windows sees that the mapped drive isn't available and then says "oh wait! I see what you want on c:\share.... I'll change my settings to that" I want to stop it from doing that and keeping the original settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that installing SP1 for Windows 7 stopped the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried making the shortcut read-only? I haven't tested it myself but I think it might work.

[Edit]When you double click a network drive to reconnect it, are you prompted for a password? Did you definitely click the "Reconnect at logon" option when you mapped the drive?[/Edit]

Comment: Hi James. Good idea but that didn't work either.

Comment: When you double click a network drive to reconnect it, are you prompted for a password? Did you definitely click the "Reconnect at logon" option when you mapped the drive?

Comment: Yep, Reconnect at logon is definitely checked. And no, there is no prompt for a password.